# How To Use SVG As Image In Carousel

Tags: html, css

Greetings Coders Please Someone Help Me To Use **SVG PATH D** In Bootstrap 4 Caraousel.. [Something Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueaXu.jpg) ...

I want To Make My Caraousel In That Shape (All Images)..

https://exill.tn/demo/plex_html/template/triangle.html

https://exill.tn/demo/plex_html/template/img/home-area.jpg

--> Here Is HTML

```
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 683 75 1366 0 1366 -150 0 -150 0 0z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: you can just use an .svg file as a src attribute to an img.

Comment: when you say that you want it to be part of the carousel do you mean that it should be the bottom part of the image and change when the "next" arrow is clicked/ or purely sit below the carousel?

Answer (score 1):

Add your SVG code in the correct section as carousel-item

```
<div id="carouselIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slide-3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <!-- add svg in carousel -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1366 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
             <path d="M0 0 683 75 1366 0 1366 -150 0 -150 0 0z"></path>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselIndicators" role="button" data- 
 slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```